# Перекодировать half-precision floating point

Tags: c#, математика

Получаю данные в формате Формат значений Hmax, Qmax, Umax, Vmax, H, Q, U, V - «укороченный» вариант формата стандарта IEEE-754 (двухбайтная мантисса).
То есть Half-precision floating point. Необходимо их перекодировать в значение.
Нашел такую [библиотеку](http://sourceforge.net/p/csharp-half/code/HEAD/tree/), но совершенно не смекну, как ей пользоваться.

В общем, задача свелась в следующему: как сложить несколько шестнадцатеричных чисел (1f + 3e + a7)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользоваться очень просто:

```
byte[] Hmax = {0x58, 0xd0}; // Порядок байтов big-endian
Half h1 = Half.ToHalf(Hmax, 0); 
Console.Write(h1);
```

Comment: Это использование библиотеки? А можно подробнее, как её подключать. И что означает код выше? У меня число из 4 байт, нужно перевести в иеее 754 укороченный.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека битая

```
 Byte[] data = new Byte[7];
 Int32 bytes = sp.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
 string all = BitConverter.ToString(data);
```